# In App Purchases - empty product list

Tags: ios, sdk, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to understand how to work with In App Purchases. I've read many documents and seen a lot sample codes but I can't understand why product list is empty. According to documentation and forums I made this:

1. Setup contracts on iTunes connect.
2. Create AppID on provision portal with unique bundle ID
3. Create and install provision profile for this AppId and enable In App Purchases
4. Create application on iTunes connect.
5. Create purchases for this application.
6. Submit application.
7. Reject application.

In code, I've tried to receive product information by product ID and as result I can see empty list. However, I can see an array of invalid product IDs.

Could you help me to understand what is wrong?

Thanks.

---

According to Apple documentation:

> Follow these steps to test your application in the sandbox.
>   - Log out from your iTunes account on the test iOS device.
>   - Before you can test your application, you must first log out of your regular iTunes account. iOS 3.0 includes a Store category in the Settings application. To log out of your iTunes account, exit your application, launch the Settings application and click the Store icon. Sign out from the currently active account.
>   - Important: Do not sign in with your test account in the Settings application.
>   - Launch your application.
>   - Once you have signed out of your account, exit Settings and launch your application. As you make purchases from your application’s store, Store Kit prompts you to authenticate the transaction. Log in using your test account to approve the payment. No financial transaction takes place, but transactions complete as if a payment was made.

I've tried it and can't see "Store Kit prompts you to authenticate" when I ask for products. Maybe I need to setup project in xCode?

---

Hm...

I can see products in Simulator of iOS 5 but can't buy it. Magic.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete your build and app on your device. I think this one should work.

Comment: I tried. Same result. I can see products only on iOS 5 simulator. Same problem with Game Center.

Answer (score 1):

It can take a good few hours for Apple's server to get round to enabling the in-app buys. I had the same problem that you did, but then it just started working half a day later.